# Possible to set default CloudKit container not based on application name?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When I turn on `CloudKit` in Xcode, it set and create a default container *based on the name of the app*. Is it possible to set a different default name? I do not want to see a new container name on the list in CloudKit dashboard, but use an existing one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can override in `Info.plist` the Bundle Identifier field. That will have change the default container ID. I changed it `com.kukodajanos.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)` to `com.kukodajanos.Dating`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Janos answer is correct, although I think you even after selecting a different iCloud container, you also have to say so in your code?

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.kukodajanos.Dating")
let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
let privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
```

I may be wrong of course, that's just the way I found it to work.

Comment: this is the preferred way, since extensions will basically ignore the `info.plist` file and use their bundle id as the container.