# How to store data on cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I've successfully stored an app's data on the cloudkit, but when I tried to store the second app, there was an error like this:

> "CKError 0x600001 d719b0:" Permission Failure"(10/2007); server
>   message ="CREATE operation not allowed"; UUID =
>   D41B3F33-102B-411D-9CE7-183CD04569DA; container ID =
>   iCloud.com.codery.ntd>"

Here is my code:

```
let now = Date()
    let timeInterval:TimeInterval = now.timeIntervalSince1970
    let timeStamp = Int(timeInterval)
    let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let bookID = CKRecord.ID(recordName: "\(timeStamp)")
    let book = CKRecord(recordType: "Book", recordID: bookID)
    book.setValue("Swift", forKey: "name")

    publicDB.save(book) { savedRecord , error in

        if error == nil {

            print("success")

        }else {


            print(error)

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CREATE operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27560627/create-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: Are you using the same cloud kit container? Normally you get a unique container for every app; and you need to specify within your second app that it want to use the container created for the first. I don't recall, but you may need to specify within code too when you open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the answer.

[Possible to set default CloudKit container not based on application name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053439/possible-to-set-default-cloudkit-container-not-based-on-application-name)

```
let container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.com.kukodajanos.Dating")
let publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
let privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
```

Is the identifier shown here the same for BOTH apps.